# Graph overlay that doesn't obscure the data

Tags: info-visualisation, visual-design, charts, information, graphs

I'm building an app that renders a line graph of the user's wellness over time.

(For example:)

[image: line graph]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://speckycdn.sdm.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/04-clean-line-chart.jpg))</sub>

It also needs to mark the days they took medication. Originally, I wanted to place a dot at the bottom of the graph on any day the user took meds, but I also don't want to limit the number of medications they're tracking, and stacking dots doesn't work too well.

How would you represent that concept?

Comment: Cursor hover tooltips appear at a pre-set distance from the cursor, so you can move them both away to see the obscured part. Why not use that?

Comment: The user needs to be able to compare treatments to wellness at a glance, no tooltip-hunting

Comment: Then half-transparent mark and half-transparent contrast outline. Like white subtitles with black outline, only somewhat transparent, so as not to occlude the graph behind it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what the two different lines (orange, blue) represent. But as an indicator you could highlight the data point from that particular day in a different color and add the number of medications inside.
[image: Scribble]